# Creating a dictionary from another dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of the type:

```
IDictionary<foo, IEnumerable<bar>> my_dictionary
```

bar class looks like this:

```
class bar
{
    public bool IsValid {get; set;} 
}
```

How can I create another dictionary with only those items that have IsValid = true.

I tried this:

```
my_dictionary.ToDictionary( p=> p.Key,
                            p=> p.Value.Where (x => x.IsValid));
```

The problem with above code is that this creates a key with empty enumerable, if all the elements for that key were IsValid = false.

for example:

```
my_dictionar[foo1] = new List<bar> { new bar {IsValid = false}, new bar {IsValid = false}, new bar {IsValid = false}};
my_dictionary[foo2] = new List<bar> {new bar {IsValid = true} , new bar{IsValid = false};
var new_dict = my_dictionary.ToDictionary( p=> p.Key,
                            p=> p.Value.Where (x => x.IsValid));
// Expected new_dict should contain only foo2 with a list of 1 bar item.
// actual is a new_dict with foo1 with 0 items, and foo2 with 1 item.
```

How do I get my expected.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Something like this?

```
my_dictionary
    .Where(p=> p.Value.Any(x => x.IsValid))
    .ToDictionary( p=> p.Key,
                   p=> p.Value.Where (x => x.IsValid));
```

That will only include items where at least one of the values `IsValid`.

Comment: +1 OP needs to filter the collection using `Where` before calling `ToDictionary`

Comment: is this first Where clause not enough to get rid of x=>!x.IsValid ? Can You not just write .ToDictionary(p=>p.Key, p=>p.Value), since that where clause before calling ToDictionary is already applying filtering?

Comment: @Prokurors: No, because we're acting on an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<foo, IEnumerable<bar>>>`, it's a little more complicated than that. The first .Where() is checking whether *any* `bar` in each KeyValuePair is valid, but it's not actually filtering the `bar`s themselves to only include valid ones. If you had a `KeyValuePair` whose value contained a mix of valid and invalid, the invalid ones would still need to be filtered out later.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dictionary.Where(p => p.Any(v => v.Value.IsValid())
             .ToDictionary(p=> p.Key,
                           p=> p.Value.Where(x => x.Value.IsValid());
```

Get Only the Items that have a true in the Value, then only get the items that are true into the new dictonary.

Filter then create the dictonary

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_dict = my_dictionary.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<foo, List<bar>>(
                                                 x.Key,
                                                 x.Value
                                                  .Where(y => y.IsValid)
                                                  .ToList()))
                            .Where(x => x.Value.Count > 0)
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.AsReadOnly());
```